# Fragments reinstantiating and adding to activity by themselves

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have viewPager with adapter where I instantiate fragment and return it in getItem() method. So when Im on the first page I have only 2 fragments alive. When I rotate the phone, they both get destroyed and garbage collected (system calls their onDestroy() and onDetach() and I can see them in .hprof memory dump as ready to be garbage collected). However, when a new activity is created with new viewpager and 2 new fragments, for some reason, system creates 2 more fragments for those that were destroyed previously and attaches them to the activity, while not adding them to viewPager at all. They just sit in fragmentManager's mActive and mAdded arrays. When I rotate device few times, it creates these new instances each time. Now, this may seem like a leak that causes fragments not to be garbage collected but they indeed are. All these fragments have different @xxx number and are atached to a new activity within a new fragment manager. I've tried everything, any help or suggestions are much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: This is how ViewPager works. Which is your question?

Comment: well I have other viewPagers, that I use in similar way, and they dont do it. there are always only fragments that is being shown and the ones next to it. but when i rotate the phone, they all get destroyed and are not recreated again. I mean, the viewPager probably works as expected, because it should be destroying all the fragments on screen rotation. I just dont undestand why they are being recreated with no purpose

Answer (score 1):

ViewPager handles the lifecycle of the Fragments it shows. As you mention it creates the visible Fragment and the ones next to it (if used with a `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`) to be able to smoothly swipe into them when the time comes. When the fragment is out of sight, it can be destoryed and recreated by the `ViewPager` at its will.

The default beheavior for a rotating screen is that the activity is recreated together with the `ViewPager` and the `Fragments`.
However this can be changed.
With `android:configChanges="orientation"` in the manifest you can prevent the activity of being recreated upon orientation change. 
The other way of preserving the fragment instance upon an orientation change is to call `setRetainInstance(true)` in the fragment to be retained.

Comment: Well thats almost what happens in my case. Im looking at the first page, then I rotate screen. Activity is destroyed, fragments are destroyed. New activity created with new fragment manager and new viewpager with new adpater. Now fragment  manager creates 2 new fragments and adds them to the activity and to viewPager's adapter. So far so good, but what happens additionaly is that FragmentManager creates 2 more fragments and ONLY attaches them to activity without adding them to viewpager's adapter. Now I have 4 fragments.When I rotate again it creates 2 normal fragments and 4 of these.and so on

Comment: Are you sure you are not looking at old discarded instances of the Fragments?

Comment: I put breakpiont in onCreateView of this fragment. first I enter the activity it is called twice. after first rotation 4 times, then 6 times and so on. these fragments get discarded. but in their place it always creatoes a same ammount of them and 2 more that are being added and shown to user

Answer (score 0):

So I it was (unexpectedly:D) bad code. I had in my Activity's onRestoreInstanceState() piece of code that was creating and setting new adapter and so it put old fragments in background. Sorry for bothering with unanswerable question.